# Convert Pyspark DataFrame to multi-dimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame of over 100 million rows of data `df`, `df` is basically like:

| row | col | ax1 | ax2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 996 | 965 | 12 | 8 | 10000 |
| 236 | 1015 | 8 | 8 | 10001 |
| 26 | 315 | 4 | 7 | 10002 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I'm trying to convert it to a numpy array, with the shape (1024, 1024, 16, 16), and save it to driver. The content of expected numpy array `arr` is like:

```
arr[996, 995, 12, 8] = 10000
arr[236, 1015, 8, 8] = 10001
.
.
.
```

I've tried to use `df.collect()`, to collect the data to driver and iterate over the DataFrame to write into `arr`. But the driver machine is just out of memory.

Comment: What are you going to do with the data on the driver? Apparently it does not fit in the memory of ther driver, so you either need to increase the memory of the driver or save the data to multiple files and proccess them one by one on the driver.

Comment: I need to feed a lot of (64, 64, 16, 16) shape array data to my deep learning model, so I need the (1024, 1024, 16, 16) shape data collect to driver, and slice the data to feed into the model. I can't slice data on executor because it is two complicated. Any solutions?

Comment: I calculated the occupation of the ```df```, which is 5 * 100 million Byte, but when I run ```df.collect()```, the memory on my driver just increase to over 10GB, that's so weird